# Jenkins C++ performance plugin

Tags: c++, continuous-integration

Is there a [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) plug-in that can show profiling/performance on C++ programs?
Something like getting [`gprof`](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof.html) results, as [`cobertura`](https://cobertura.github.io/cobertura/) does for [`gcovr`](http://gcovr.com).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/Jenkins-Cpp-builds.html#GPROF

That explains how to do exactly what you want