# Seeking Jenkins plugins for C/C++ code

Tags: c++, c, jenkins

I want to have as much information as I can from builds, especially with trend lines.

Currently I am using the following Jenkins plug-ins:

- compiler warnings
- CppCheck for Linting
- xUnit for Google Test results
- code coverage of the unit tests
- valgrind for memory leaks
- DogyGen

Are there any other C/C++ plug-ins for Jenkins, of which I am not aware?

(See also [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4516/jenkins-c-performance-plugin), which asked for profiling)

---

[Update] I just found [the SLOCC plug-in](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SLOCCount+Plugin), which shows lines of code.

Comment: Beyond just knowing if there are other plug-ins, what are your requirements for the C/C++ type plug-ins?  What is it you are looking for exactly?

Comment: Not exactly C++ specific, but you may want to look also at [Static Code Analysis Plug-ins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Static+Code+Analysis+Plug-ins), at the top of the page there is a list of supported plug-ins (CheckStyle, Task Scanner, ...).